# Why my deployment check failing here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upgrade capistrano from v2 to v3. My deployment failing here

My git path is

**$ which git**

/usr/bin/git

**$ /usr/bin/env git --version**

git version 1.8.5.2

**$ cap development deploy:check**

```
 INFO [bc6a1c31] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/ on 40.17.329.77
DEBUG [bc6a1c31] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/ )
 INFO [bc6a1c31] Finished in 4.281 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [63f3b4b8] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh on 40.17.329.77
DEBUG [63f3b4b8] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh )
 INFO [63f3b4b8] Finished in 0.627 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [f2bd4b22] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:example/webapp.giton 40.17.329.77
DEBUG [f2bd4b22] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:example/webapp.git)
DEBUG [f2bd4b22]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [f2bd4b22]    git
DEBUG [f2bd4b22]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [f2bd4b22]    
DEBUG [f2bd4b22] Finished in 0.627 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).
```

Comment: Looks like the git executable on your remote machine is not in your PATH. Make sure git is in the system PATH variable of the user that you are using to deploy remotely. For example in the .bashrc of the remote machine's user you can add something like: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/<path where you git executable is>`

Comment: @ Rico - I have git in my app path. Already I am using capistrano 2 to deploy the same app. It accepts my git path. Through that I can do all operations(git pull, push). But why my git path is not accepted with capistrano 3 for the same app?

Comment: Are you able to access to remove pc via ssh?

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/env git` from the command line on the remote machine? Also, can you post the output of `/usr/bin/env` on the remote machine.

Comment: @ Rico - Thanks. Git is not in the remote machine. Thanks a lot. Kindly post this as answer. I will accept.

Comment: login under your deploy user and try `$ git --version` if there is no git just setup it under the user

Comment: did you get this figured out ?

Comment: @Rico - yes.Kindly post this as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git is not in the remote machine:

If running Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

If running CentOS/RedHat (run as root):

```
yum install git
```

Comment: I did the same Even In my case Git is already install ..Will you please tell what mistake I did .